# Installing mod_mono may uninstall the PHP Apache module. Apparently they cannot co-exist

Tags: mono, apache2

Why is it that installing `mod_mono` may uninstall the PHP Apache module? Apparently they cannot co-exist.

What is the reason? Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [Ubuntu-only bug](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ModMono), please [report it to them](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bugs). I have both modules running on various machines, installed using the package manager, without any problems.

Answer (score 2):

mod_mono does **not** conflict at all with mod_php. That might be a packaging problem of the distribution that you are using.

Comment: Please see it here https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ModMono. Do you know why that packaging problem exists

Comment: I have an Ubuntu VM with PHP installed and I have installed mod_mono from sources without a problem.